# How to get around timing issue in Android

Tags: android, asynchronous

I'm storing one of the menu items from my activity as a class field, when inside `onCreateOptionsMenu()`.

```
_myMenuItem = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.menu_item);
```

But in `onCreate()` I call an async method, and the result of that dictates whether I should make the visibility true or false on said menu item; for example:

```
if (someCondition) {
  _myMenuItem.setVisible(true);
}
```

The problem is sometimes the async method completes (and that above code is called) before the menu is inflated, causing a null pointer exception.

How can I resolve this timing issue? Ideally without putting the async call inside `onCreateOptionsMenu()` if anyone knows of a good way. Thanks

Comment: `Bind first` after that call your `async method`....

Comment: Could you please explain more?

Comment: could you please post your full activity code ?

Answer (score 0):

Declare a boolean property in the Activity. After completing the background work set that property to true if menu item is to be shown, to false otherwise and force the menu to be refreashed (call `invalidateOptionsMenu`). Refreshing options menu causes `onPrepareOptionsMenu` to be called. In onPrepareOptionsMenu check the value of your property and set the visibility of menu item.